# How to trigger the function every day at a specific time

Tags: android, android-studio, timer

I am developing and android app. This app has several activities. I need the application, regardless of which activity it displays, to execute a query on the server at 2 a.m. every day. I am currently using Timer and TimerTask, as follows:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                makePostToServer()
            }
        };

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, getDate(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // 24 h


private Date getDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        return cal.getTime();

}
```

Is there a chance that for some reason a Timer launched at the start of the application will stop working?
Because the server logs do not always contain information about the executed query. It's as if it didn't happen.
Maybe there is a better way to call functions every day at 2.
Best regards

Comment: Actually this should be done on server side using CRON. But if you wish to trigger server from mobile side use WorkManager (https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712) or any other job schedular library.

Comment: Use Alarmmanager to acheive this. go through this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this use work manager for your need which is very efficient. In this case you can use **periodic work manager**.

Check out this for reference.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

*Happy Coding!!*

Answer (score 0):

There are several APIs available to schedule tasks in Android:

1. Alarm Manager
2. Job Scheduler
3. GCM Network Manager
4. Firebase Job Dispatcher
5. Sync Adapter

You can find a lot of sample easily.